# Not Getting Custom Field value on Custom Form save action in sitecore 9.0.1

Tags: sitecore-forms, custom-field

I have created a custom field in Sitecore 9.0.1 as `conditional rendering` having One `radio button` and based on `radio button` selection i am showing and hiding the fields which are `label` and `text box`.

So my requirement is that when someone select yes then show `TextBox` that is mandatory and finally on Submission of the form I need that `TextBox` field value?

Comment: Sitecore 9.1 conditional rendering is out of box,better upgrade to latest Sitecore version. already one question is raised please check https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/17998/how-to-add-conditional-field-in-sitecore-9-form.

Comment: Could you please let me know how you are hiding/showing textbox?

Comment: Hi @SwatiGupta Please find the script below, which I am using for show and hide functionality

Comment: @kohilavani Sorry I did not find any script. Can you please script in your question?

Comment: Hi @SwatiGupta Please find the script below
$(document).on("click", ".sample", function () {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            var clickedID = '#' + id;           
            var conditions = $(clickedID).parent().parent().children('#Condition').val(); 
            var classname = $(this).attr('class');
            if (conditions == 'Yes' )
                {if (conditions == 'Yes' && Action == "Enable" && Select ==TextBox") 
{ $(clickedID).parent().parent().find('#divText').css('display', 'block');}
and likewise i am checking other cases too.

Comment: @kohilavani As I mentioned below you can set aria-required ,required,data-val attribute

Answer (score 0):

You can check logic in this link [How to add Conditional field in sitecore 9 Form?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/17998/how-to-add-conditional-field-in-sitecore-9-form/18000#18000) where I am hiding `Sections`, you can hide text box.

To apply mandatory logic you can play with `aria-required` ,`required`,`data-val` attribute

Comment: Can you provide some more context to flesh out the link in your answer? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Answer (score 0):

I used a similar approach, where selecting "other" list item from the drop down will show a text box and I get the value on the submit action. Maybe this will help you to update your code.

1. The model for that custom field will look like this.

   ```
    using System;
    using Sitecore.Data.Items;
    using Sitecore.Diagnostics;
    using Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Models.Fields;

    namespace Universal.Feature.Forms.CustomModels
    {
    [Serializable]
    public class OtherOptionDropDownListViewModel : DropDownListViewModel
    {
        public string OtherOptionLabel { get; set; }
        public string OtherOptionUserValue { get; set; }
        public string OtherOptionValue { get; set; }
        public string otherOptionDropListFieldName { get; set; }

        protected override void InitItemProperties(Item item)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(item, "item");
            base.InitItemProperties(item);

            OtherOptionValue = item?.Fields[FormsConstants.ItemConstants.OtherOptionValue]?.Value;
            OtherOptionLabel = item?.Fields[FormsConstants.ItemConstants.OtherOptionLabel]?.Value;
            otherOptionDropListFieldName = item?.Fields[FormsConstants.ItemConstants.OtherOptionFieldName]?.Value;
        }

        protected override void UpdateItemFields(Item item)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(item, "item");
            base.UpdateItemFields(item);

            var value = item.Fields[FormsConstants.ItemConstants.OtherOptionValue];
            if (value != null)
            {
                value.SetValue(OtherOptionValue, true);
            }

            var label = item.Fields[FormsConstants.ItemConstants.OtherOptionLabel];
            if (label != null)
            {
                label.SetValue(OtherOptionLabel, true);
            }

            var fieldName =     item.Fields[FormsConstants.ItemConstants.OtherOptionFieldName];
            if (fieldName != null)
            {
                fieldName.SetValue(otherOptionDropListFieldName, true);
            }
        }
    }
    }
   ```

The cshtml will look like this.

```
@using Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Html
@model Universal.Feature.Forms.CustomModels.OtherOptionDropDownListViewModel

<div class="universalotheroptionselectlist">
    <label for="@Html.IdFor(m => Model.Value)"     class="@Model.LabelCssClass">@Html.DisplayTextFor(t => Model.Title)</label>
    <select id="@Html.IdFor(m => Model.Value)" name="@Html.NameFor(m => Model.Value)" data-sc-otheroption="@Model.OtherOptionValue" class="@Model.CssClass universalotheroptionselectlist-ddn" data-sc-tracking="@Model.IsTrackingEnabled" data-sc-field-name="@Model.Name" @Html.GenerateUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes(m => m.Value)>
        @if (Model.ShowEmptyItem)
        {
            <option label=" "></option>
        }
    @foreach (var item in Model.Items)
         {
             <option value="@item.Value" selected="@item.Selected">@item.Text</option>
         }
    </select>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.Value)


    <div class="universalotheroptioninputfield">
    <label for="@Html.IdFor(m => Model.OtherOptionUserValue)" class="@Model.LabelCssClass universalotheroptionselectlist-label">@Html.DisplayTextFor(t => Model.OtherOptionLabel)</label>
    <textarea  id="@Html.IdFor(m => Model.OtherOptionUserValue)" name="@Html.NameFor(m => Model.OtherOptionUserValue)" class="@Model.CssClass universalotheroptionselectlist-input" data-sc-tracking="@Model.IsTrackingEnabled" data-sc-field-name="@Model.Name" ></textarea>
</div>
```

And finally, the JS to set the value.

```
let UniversalOtherOptionSelectList = function (selectListComponent) {
this.selectListComponent = selectListComponent;
this.dropdown = this.selectListComponent.querySelector('.universalotheroptionselectlist-ddn');
this.textBox = this.selectListComponent.querySelector('.universalotheroptionselectlist-input');
this.otherOptionDiv =     this.selectListComponent.querySelector('.universalotheroptioninputfield');
this.otherOptionValue = this.dropdown.getAttribute("data-sc-otheroption");
};
UniversalOtherOptionSelectList.prototype.Init = function () {
var _this = this;

_this.RenderOtherOptionControl();

this.dropdown.addEventListener('change', function () {
    _this.RenderOtherOptionControl();
});
};

UniversalOtherOptionSelectList.prototype.RenderOtherOptionControl = function () {

var _this = this;
var selectedValue = this.dropdown.value;

if (_this.otherOptionValue === selectedValue) {
    _this.otherOptionDiv.style.display = "inline-block";
    _this.textBox.value = "";
} else {
    _this.otherOptionDiv.style.display = "none";
}
};


window.addEventListener('load', function () {
let selectLists = document.querySelectorAll('.universalotheroptionselectlist');

if (selectLists) {
    selectLists.forEach(function (selectListComponent) {
        // Construct new OtherOptionSelectList
        var selectList = new UniversalOtherOptionSelectList(selectListComponent);

        // Init functionality on load
        selectList.Init();
    });
    }
});
```

And on the custom save action, I get the value in FormSubmitContext formSubmitContext. Make sure that you have the custom field properly set in core database. And match the csthml with your cshtml.